# GCM onRegistered not called

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

The onRegistered method never gets called, in the logcat I see the last line as acquiring wakelock.

> - 09-26 14:03:23.285: D/GCMRegistrar(15820): resetting backoff for
> - 09-26 14:03:23.285: V/GCMRegistrar(15820): Registering app *a of senders 735175912799
> - 09-26 14:03:23.895: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(15820): onReceive: - com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION 09-26 14:03:23.895:
>     V/GCMRegistrar(15820): Setting the name of retry receiver class to
>     *.notifications.MyGCMBroadcastReceiver
> - 09-26 14:03:23.895: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(15820): GCM IntentService class: - *.notifications.GCMIntentService
> - 09-26 14:03:23.903: V/GCMBaseIntentService(15820): Acquiring wakelock

I have my own Broadcastreceiver:

```
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver;

public class MyGCMBroadcastReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName (Context context) {
        return GCMIntentService.class.getCanonicalName();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar problem. It turned out that I forgot to add  to ApplicationManifest.xml:

```xml
<service android:name=".GCMIntentService"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following are common solutions:

1) Name you service as `"GCMIntentService"`

2) Put your `GCMIntentService` in default package

3) before sending GCM register request call

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
```

So that if there is any problem with your device or menifest it will tell you.
4) check permissions. Particularly check package mane in permissions. This is a nesty on, if you mess up with package name in permission, it will work for latest androids(Jelly Bean +) but will fail in lower devices